# sum and count with joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

Haven't come across a situation like this so not sure how to correct it.  I'm guessing a sub query is needed?

I need the SUM of `votes.vote` and the COUNT of `votes.vote`.  This allows me to calculate a rating (sum of all votes / # of votes = rating) for the location selected.

Here is the query with * and static binding to make it easier to understand :

```
//prepare
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        *,
        COALESCE(SUM(votes.vote),0) AS vote_total,
        COUNT(votes.vote) AS number_votes
    FROM locations
    LEFT JOIN tables
        ON tables.location_id = locations.location_id
    LEFT JOIN votes
        ON votes.location_id = locations.location_id
    LEFT JOIN events
        ON events.location_id = locations.location_id
    WHERE locations.location_id = :location_id
    LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
");

//bindings
$binding = array(
    'location_id' => 11,
    'limit' => 20,
    'offset' => 0
);

//execute
$stmt->execute($binding);

//results
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

There are 11 events joined to this location.  There are only two votes joined to it (a value of 3 and a value of 4).  I am getting the following :

```
[vote_total] => 77 (should be 7, but is 7*11)
[number_votes] => 22 (should be 2, but is 2*11)
```

Aside from that only one result is returned rather than 11.  If I remove the `votes` table join and the SUM/COUNT selects for it all 11 results are shown as they should be.

Is it possible to get the SUM and COUNT totals for votes.vote in the same query in some way or will a separate query be needed just to get those values?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You are clearly confused, because you have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` and that will return 1 row.  Yet, you are using a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: There shouldn't be a group by... sample return was supplied regarding the question at hand.  Yes, limit and offset are used because paging is involved... the query has been dumbed down for this post.  So, like I said in my post... is it possible or will a separate query be needed to get the sum/count of that specific column for all results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess based on your description of the problem is that you want one row per event.  If so:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.*
       COALESCE(SUM(v.vote), 0) AS vote_total,
       COUNT(v.vote) AS number_votes
FROM locations l LEFT JOIN
     tables
     ON t.location_id = l.location_id LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     ON v.location_id = l.location_id LEFT JOIN
     events e
     ON e.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE l.location_id = :location_id
GROUP BY e.event_id
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset;
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, but I guess I'm not understanding why grouping by the event.event_id was necessary here?  All the events are unique and there can never be two events with the same event_id.

Comment: @user756659 . . . As  I explained in the comment, an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row.  Your use of `SUM()` and `COUNT()` make this an aggregation query.